# Error: duplicated outer port

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

I've been following this tutorial on docker cloud:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/load-balance-hello-world/

I've been getting errors when trying to expose port 80 using haproxy.

DEFAULT

[image: default]

when i check port 80, the ports move and port 1936 gets checked automatically

[image: when i check port 80, the ports move and port 1936 gets checked automatically]

try unpublishing 1936

[image: try unpublishing 1936]

launch, duplicated outer port
[image: launch, duplicated outer port]

unpublish 1936

[image: unpublish 1936]

same error

[image: same error]

Comment: I think there is a problem with Docker Cloud because this didn't happen before for me but it happens everytime for me now.

Comment: I posted https://forums.docker.com/t/publishing-haproxy-ports-causes-duplicate-ports/17810.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure this out using the UI. I believe this is a bug that was introduced recently. But as somebody suggested on Docker forums, you can use the CLI instead. I was able to create a new proxy on Cloud with this command

```
docker-cloud service create -n haproxy --autorestart ON_FAILURE --role global -p 80:80 --link-service demo-blue:demo-blue dockercloud/haproxy
docker-lcoud service start <UUID>
```

You should be able to do something similar as well.